# "Transaction cannot have multiple recordsets with this cursor type." Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, recordset, cursor-position

I am getting the following error in my classic asp application:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> Transaction cannot have multiple recordsets with this cursor type.
>   Change the cursor type, commit the transaction, or close one of the
>   recordsets.

i am working on migrating the code from Oracle to SQL Server 2008, and this is an issue that i keep seeing here and there, all through out the application.

can't seem to find any fixes for it.

this particular case in this block of code: (i changed the selects to make them shorter)

```
Set MyConn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Call OpenORPSConnect(MyConn)
ql = "Select username from mytable"
set rs = MyConn.Execute(sql)
if not rs.EOF then username = rs(0)
if username = "" then username = theUser
rs.close()
set rs = nothing

MyConn.BeginTrans()

sql = "Select someReport from MyTable"
set rs = MyConn.Execute(sql)

do while not rs.EOF
TIMESTAMP       = rs("TIMESTAMP")
rev      = rs("REV")

select case whatChange
    case "Target date"
       sql = "Insert into " & caJustTable & _
                 " (TEXT, TIMESTAMP, CURRENTFLAG)" & _
            " Values ( Text& "','" & COPY_TS & "', 'Y')""
MyConn.Execute(sql) 
    end select

sql = "update table, set this to that"
MyConn.Execute(sql) <-------- error happens here sometimes....

end if
rs.movenext
loop

rs.close()
set rs = nothing
```

Comment: I think your problem is your MyConn.BeginTrans() has no commit after the first Execute.  If you commit that then your next execute should work just fine or you may consider moving the select outside the transaction, no need to have it in there.

Comment: @Robert, where should i put it? honestly, i'm not even sure why the BeginTrans is there in the first place...

Comment: you can just remove it if you want.  It's there in the case that something fails on your insert you can rollback and not lose existing data. - http://www.firstsql.com/tutor5.htm

Comment: there is a rollback option in SQL Server. - MyConn.RollbackTrans

Comment: Was the transaction not important for making sure all (or none) of the edits happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since this was answered in the comments I wanted to turn it into a better answer**

Your problem seems to be the `MyConn.BeginTrans()` has no `MyConn.CommitTrans()` or `MyConn.RollbackTrans()` after the Insert Statement in your select case; therefore, an error is thrown when you try to update the data. If you commit or Rollback after that insert execute then your next execute should work just fine.  The fact that the MyConn.BeginTrans() is before a simple select statement you might consider moving it after the select.

I would do something like this (if you want to use transactions):

```
'MyConn.BeginTrans()

sql = "Select someReport from MyTable"
set rs = MyConn.Execute(sql)

do while not rs.EOF
   TIMESTAMP = rs("TIMESTAMP")
   rev = rs("REV")

  select case whatChange
    case "Target date"
        MyConn.BeginTrans()
        sql = "Insert into " & caJustTable & _
                 " (TEXT, TIMESTAMP, CURRENTFLAG)" & _
            " Values ( Text& "','" & COPY_TS & "', 'Y')""
        MyConn.Execute(sql) 
        MyConn.CommitTrans() 'You'll want to validate your data inserts properly before committing
    end select

    MyConn.BeginTrans()
    sql = "update table, set this to that"
    MyConn.Execute(sql) <-------- error happens here sometimes....
    MyConn.CommitTrans()'You'll want to validate your data inserts properly before committing

  end if
  rs.movenext
loop

rs.close()
set rs = nothing
```

Transactions are generally used for inserting/updating or deleting data.  Since you commented you don't know why the BeginTrans() statement is there then yes you could remove it altogether but I would recommend reading up on transactions and making sure you don't need it after your insert and update statements which occur later in the code.

Here is a reference for SQL transactions:

http://www.firstsql.com/tutor5.htm

Comment: hm. the strange this is... when i go through with a debugger i don't get the error. but if i do the same thing without the debugger on it breaks on me.... could it be a timing issue? where it has time to process when i slowly go through the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think MyConn may need to be closed at the end.  Is this something you can try??

Comment: its being used after the block of code i showed here.... this is also an "include" file and the "conn" is passed in as a variable...if i close it, it might now work with other includes

Comment: The other possible problem is that you are using the same MyConn to execute two separate sql statements, one inside and one outside the while loop - try using different connections.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an open recordset on the connection, so I think the problem is that your database does not support additional actions on the same connection until the recordset is closed. As a fix, I would recommend one of three options:

1. Use a second connection (on which you run the transaction) to run the sql statements that update the table.
2. Collect all statements into a list while you loop through the recordset, close the recordset, and then run the statements (using the same connection).
3. Or pull the data into a data table and loop through that rather than an open recordset.